# AVAssetWriter to Multiple Files

Tags: swift, ffmpeg, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avassetwriter

I have an `AVCaptureSession` that consists of an `AVCaptureScreenInput` and a `AVCaptureDeviceInput`. Both are hooked up as data output delegates, and I'm using an `AVAssetWriter` to write to a single MP4 file.

When writing to a single MP4 file, everything works. When I try to switch between multiple AVAssetWriters to save to successive files every 5 seconds, there is a slight audio drop when concatting all files together via FFMPEG.

Example joined video (notice the small audio drop every 5 seconds):

https://youtu.be/lrqD5dcbUXg

After lots of investigation, I've settled on that this is probably due to the audio and video segments getting split/not starting on the same timestamp.

I've now gotten to a point where I know my algorithm should work, but I'm at a loss on how to split an audio `CMBufferSample`. It seems like this might be useful [CMSampleBufferCopySampleBufferForRange](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremedia/1489461-cmsamplebuffercopysamplebufferfo?chan_10) but not sure how to split based on a a time (want a buffer with all samples before and after that time).

```
func getBufferUpToTime(sample: CMSampleBuffer, to: CMTime) -> CMSampleBuffer {
  var numSamples = CMSampleBufferGetNumSamples(sample)
  var sout: CMSampleBuffer?

  let endSampleIndex = // how do I get this?

  CMSampleBufferCopySampleBufferForRange(nil, sample, CFRangeMake(0, numSamples), &sout)

  return sout!
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `AVCaptureScreenInput`, then you're not on iOS, right? So I was going to write about splitting sample buffers, but then I remembered that on OSX, `AVCaptureFileOutput.startRecording` (*not* `AVAssetWriter`) has this tantalizing comment:

> On Mac OS X, if this method is called within the captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection: delegate method, the first samples written to the new file are guaranteed to be those contained in the sample buffer passed to that method.

Not dropping samples sounds pretty promising, so if you can live with `mov` instead of mp4 files, you should be able to get audio dropout free results by using `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`, implementing `fileOutputShouldProvideSampleAccurateRecordingStart` and calling `startRecording` from `didOutputSampleBuffer`, like this:

```
import Cocoa
import AVFoundation

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

    let session = AVCaptureSession()
    let movieFileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()

    var movieChunkNumber = 0
    var chunkDuration = kCMTimeZero // TODO: synchronize access? probably fine.

    func startRecordingChunkFile() {
        let filename = String(format: "capture-%.2i.mov", movieChunkNumber)
        let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent(filename)
        movieFileOutput.startRecording(to: url, recordingDelegate: self)

        movieChunkNumber += 1
    }

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let displayInput = AVCaptureScreenInput(displayID: CGMainDisplayID())

        let micInput = try! AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio)!)

        session.addInput(displayInput)
        session.addInput(micInput)

        movieFileOutput.delegate = self

        session.addOutput(movieFileOutput)

        session.startRunning()

        self.startRecordingChunkFile()
    }
}

extension AppDelegate: AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {
    func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {
        // NSLog("error \(error)")
    }
}

extension AppDelegate: AVCaptureFileOutputDelegate {
    func fileOutputShouldProvideSampleAccurateRecordingStart(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        if let formatDescription = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBuffer) {
            if CMFormatDescriptionGetMediaType(formatDescription) == kCMMediaType_Audio {
                let duration = CMSampleBufferGetDuration(sampleBuffer)
                chunkDuration = CMTimeAdd(chunkDuration, duration)

                if CMTimeGetSeconds(chunkDuration) >= 5 {
                    startRecordingChunkFile()
                    chunkDuration = kCMTimeZero
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias for pointing me in another direction! I'm still down one rabbit hole but will try this out in T-1 week and mark as correct if it works out!

Comment: You're welcome! Your original question is valid, but the answer is tricky - the `CMSampleBuffer` calls are so verbose, and you would like to split on sample boundaries but you seem to only have `CMTime`s, and when they're given to you by `AVCaptureSession`, their timebase is definitely not the audio sampling rate & then osx offers you this get out of jail free card.

Comment: Yep definitely. The other problem is that `CMSampleBufferCopySampleBufferForRange` will not work because the `CMSampleBuffer` only has a presentation timestamp for the first sample, which means I can assume the presentation of each sample after is uniformly distributing (according to the documentation). So I might have to manually grab data from the underlying buffer and create two `CMSampleBuffer`s. :-)